# Deploy Java code to BlackBerry device without signing keys

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I want to deploy code directly to a BlackBerry device, but I do not have any [RIM code signing keys](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/codekeys.jsp). Is there a way to do this without the keys?

Currently I am using the .cod files to deploy on a BlackBerry device simulator.

Answer (score 6):

You only need signing keys if you use BlackBerry APIs that require them (as noted in the javadocs for the classes and/or methods that require them).  Otherwise, you can build, deploy, and test your application on the phone just fine.

Comment: How?  [This error](http://i.imgur.com/qU5Dn.png) is what I get when trying to "Debug As -> Blackberry device" from Eclipse

Comment: What happens if you click "Proceed"?

Comment: Ah, persistence.  Pays off.  You get to a dialog, and it looks [like this](http://i.imgur.com/sAOPq.png).  You UNCHECK "Automatically sign.." to make it shut up about the signatures.  It works!  Cool.